# Replacing Strings In Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column as such (example):

```
1                               France
2                               France
3                              Germany
4                              Germany
5                              Germany
6                                Spain
7                                Spain
8                                Spain
175                           France.2
176                           France.2
177                          Germany.2
178                          Germany.2
179                          Germany.2
180                               UK.1
181                               UK.1
182                               UK.1
183                            Italy.2
184                            Italy.2
185                            Italy.2
```

This would be my index and df[0].

I am trying to locate the ".1" and ".2" up to ".4". and remove them.

```
rename_rows = ['.1', '.2', '.3', '.4']
for row in df[0]:
    for r in rename_rows:
        if r in row:
            df[0] = df[0].replace(r, '')
```

Nothing happens when this occurs.

If get down to the last loop "if r in row:" and I say print('True') it completes correctly. I've also tried replacing the `df[0] = df[0].replace(r, '')` to instead be `df[0] = df[0].replace(row, '')` and it successfully deletes the enter country name. However, I just want to delete the ".1" portion.

Any thoughts on why it won't delete that portion only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df[0].str.extract('^([^\.]+)')
```

Output:

```
           0
1     France
2     France
3    Germany
4    Germany
5    Germany
6      Spain
7      Spain
8      Spain
175   France
176   France
177  Germany
178  Germany
179  Germany
180       UK
181       UK
182       UK
183    Italy
184    Italy
185    Italy
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the endings you don't want by an empty string:

```
df['country'].str.replace('.[0-4]$', '')
```

Explanation of the regex: 
the $ stands for the end of the string, so when the string ends with a . followed by numbers 0 to 4, this should be replaced by an empty string.